# java Output does not match input for variables

Tags: java

Writing a main class to output from 2 other classes.  There are 6 variables being passed but only the last 3 are printing correctly.  The first 3 all return null.  Here is the output:

DOG DATA
null is a null, a null dog. 
The top trick is : Spinner.
The Corgi is 12 years old and weighs 20 pounds.

```
public class Dog {

    // instance variables
    public static String type;
    public static String breed;
    public static String name;
    public static String topTrick;

    // constructor
    public Dog(String type, String breed, String name) {
        type = "No type";
        breed = "No breed";
        name = "No name";
    }

    // methods
    public static String setTopTrick(String trick) {
        topTrick = trick;
        return trick;
    }

    // method used to print Dog information
    public String toString() {
        String temp = "\nDOG DATA\n" + name + " is a " + breed +
                ", a " + type + " dog. \nThe top trick is : " +
                topTrick + ".";
        return temp;
    }

}
```

```
ublic class Corgi extends Dog {

    // additional instance variables
    public static int weight;
    public static int age;

    // constructor
    public Corgi(String type, String breed, String name, int pounds, int years) {

        // invoke Dog class (super class) constructor
        super(type, breed, name);
        weight = pounds;
        age = years;
    }

    // mutator methods
    public static int setWeight(int pounds) {
        weight = pounds;
        return pounds;
    }
    public static int setAge(int years) {
        age = years;
        return years;
    }

    // override toString() method to include additional dog information
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (super.toString() + "\nThe Corgi is " + age +
                " years old and weighs " + weight + " pounds.");
    }

}
```

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Corgi sleeper = new Corgi("Geriatric", "Pembroke Welsh", "Ein", 20, 12);
        sleeper.setTopTrick("Spinner");
        System.out.println(sleeper);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Literally everything in your program except `main` that is static should *not* be static.  Static variables are not instance variables.

Also, your `Dog` constructor is incorrect, and should be

```
this.type = type;
this.breed = breed;
this.name = name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!